# PHPExcel formula don't returns correct value

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

The formula `=SE(D231="";"";SE(M231>=0;"C";"D"))` its always returning the "C" value, but the logic is correct and must returns "D", anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Rules for using formulae in PHPExcel (quoting directly from the [PHPExcel docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#write-a-formula-into-a-cell))

> Inside the Excel file, formulas are always stored as they would appear in an English version of Microsoft Office Excel, and PHPExcel handles all formulae internally in this format. This means that the following rules hold:
>
> - Decimal separator is '.' (period)
> - Function argument separator is ',' (comma)
> - Matrix row separator is ';' (semicolon)
> - English function names must be used

If you want to work with formulae in your native language/locale settings instead of English, then read the section of the PHPExcel documents entitled [Locale settings for Formulae](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#locale-settings-for-formulae)

Comment: This formula is present on excel sheet, the problem is not the sintax, is that always returns to me a wrong value...

If the value was <= 0, so returns "D" else returns "C", the value is negative but returns to me C, always.

Comment: The do some [debugging](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357)...... If that formula is correct in the spreadsheet, then PHPExcel should have absolutely no problem evaluating it correctly; but I can't help you blindfold, with no information, no indication of the values in the cells that are being tested by the IF().

Comment: If this helps... i'm using getFormattedValue() for takes the value of the cell...

Comment: Tell me, Mr. Baker, how to help you to help me? I'm novice in manipulation of sheets with PHP, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You need to debug PHPExcel's evaluation of the formula.... the gist that I linked previously shows how to debug formulae in PHPExcel